# preventing display of duplicate records in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using an stored procedure in SQL server, but it is giving me some duplicate records, of course I don't have duplicate records in my database, but my stored procedure is giving me two instances of a same record, what can be wrong? how can I prevent my query from giving duplicate records?
it is my SP select clause:

```
select  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Review.Point desc) ) as rownumber, 

Business.BusinessId,Business.BName,Business.BAddress1
  ,Business.BAddress2,Business.BCity,Business.BState,Business.BZipCode,Business.countryCode,Business.BPhone1,Business.BPhone2,Business.BEmail,Business.Keyword
  ,Business.BWebAddress,Business.BCatId,Business.BSubCatId,Business.BDetail,Business.bImage,Business.UCId,Business.UCConfirm
  ,Business.UOId,Business.UOConfirm,Business.x,Business.y,Cat.CatName,SubCat1.SubCatName
 from Business left outer join 
        Review on business.BusinessId=Review.BusinessId left outer join
        Cat  on business.BCatid=Cat.CatId  left outer join 
        SubCat1  on business.BSubCatid=SubCat1.SubCatId '+@sql2+' 
) as tbl
where rownumber between  '+CONVERT(varchar, @lbound)+' and '+CONVERT(varchar, @ubound);
```

Comment: Probably you have some wrong joins there. But without the SP code and an explanation of the tables involved is not possible to give an answer

Comment: It is probably a join that is giving you the duplicates. Hard to tell without seeing the query.

Comment: thanks, I've inserted my SP in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your data to dig in to your join logic, but if it duplicating across BusinessID, you could add another `ROW_NUMBER()` for the duplicates:

```
select  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Review.Point desc) ) as rownumber, 
r = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Business.BusinessId ORDER BY Business.BusinessId)
Business.BusinessId,Business.BName,Business.BAddress1
  ,Business.BAddress2,Business.BCity,Business.BState,Business.BZipCode,Business.countryCode,Business.BPhone1,Business.BPhone2,Business.BEmail,Business.Keyword
  ,Business.BWebAddress,Business.BCatId,Business.BSubCatId,Business.BDetail,Business.bImage,Business.UCId,Business.UCConfirm
  ,Business.UOId,Business.UOConfirm,Business.x,Business.y,Cat.CatName,SubCat1.SubCatName
 from Business left outer join 
        Review on business.BusinessId=Review.BusinessId left outer join
        Cat  on business.BCatid=Cat.CatId  left outer join 
        SubCat1  on business.BSubCatid=SubCat1.SubCatId '+@sql2+' 
) as tbl
where rownumber between  '+CONVERT(varchar, @lbound)+' and '+CONVERT(varchar, @ubound)
AND r = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the reserved word DISTINCT in your query.

eg

```
select distinct 
    *
from
    students s
    inner join enrollments e on e.StudentId = s.Id
    inner join courses c on c.Id = e.CourseId
```

However, unexpected duplicates in a result table is often (but not always)  a clue that you have a badly formed query or a badly designed database.

Comment: it gives me this error: image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Comment: Do you know which item is an "image data type"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this left join

```
Review on business.BusinessId=Review.BusinessId left outer join
```

seems not needed in your query and if there are more than one review for one business ...

Comment: as you can see I've used Review table, so I think it is needed, it gives me error when I remove it

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed in the rownumber. However it's this join that gives out the multiple rows because there are more than one review for a business, right?.

Comment: no, my businesses have 1 review only, but when I remove this joint, I don't have duplicates!

Comment: So if you take away the ROWNUMBER and let the join you get duplicates?